# How to call a function of a contract using web3 and infura

Tags: solidity, web3js, infura

Imagine having the below code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Message {
    address myMessage;

    function setMessage() public {
        myMessage = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Now i know that infura does not support eth_sendTransaction. and i know how to sign the transaction and send it using web3 library.

However my only confusion, how to make the contract call in the transaction itself? i dont want to send any value just make a contract call.

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/), you need to create the contract using the contracts address + abi and a signer.

```
import <Your contract deployment address>; 
import <Your contract abi>; 
const connection = await new Web3Modal().connect(); 
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection); 
const signer = provider.getSigner(); 
const contract = new Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);
```

---

You can then call the contract via :

```
 await contract.setMessage();
```

Note I used https://github.com/web3modal/web3modal here, but another way to get a signer can be found in ethers documentation.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how to connect to Rinkeby testnet with web3modal using Infura?

Answer (score 0):

@chunter 's answer is very good, for additional info, I recommand infura's official doc: https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/call-a-contract

[image]

here is an code snippet for example ( for complete code ,please refer to the official doc ):

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const fs = require('fs')

const { abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Demo.json'))

async function main(){
  const network = process.env.ETHEREUM_NETWORK

  // step1. init the web3 instance
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<YOUR INFURA PROJECT ID>`
    )
  )

  // step2. create signer
  const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(  process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY)
  web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(signer)

  // step3. create contract, abi 
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract( abi, process.env.DEMO_CONTRACT)

  // step4. create tx , here we used the signature
  const tx = contract.methods.echo(" Hi hihihi ")
  const receipt = await tx
    .send({ from: signer.address, gas: await tx.estimateGas() })
    .once("transactionHash" , (txHash) => {
      console.info("mining transaction...", txHash)
    })

  console.info("mined in block: ", receipt.blockNumber)
}

require('dotenv').config()
main()
```